# Calls Payment Issue

Tags: contract-invocation

If I understood right, calls (unlike the transactions) are not added to the block thus they are not paid. Why can not I make an SC aka

```
while (true)
```

and paralyze a validator

Comment: You mean "Why can not I make a function in an SC, which does `while (true)`". You can, but it won't paralyze the validator, because unlike transactions, calls are simply not validated. It would "paralyze" the node that you're connected to (i.e., your web3 provider, which in turn will eventually stop giving you service).

Answer (score 0):

Because calls still have a virtual transaction fee and Ethereum node will terminate your JSON-RPC call eventually.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that calls are not even validated. At most, you'd be "paralyzing" your web3 provider (i.e., the node that you're connected to), which will eventually stop giving you service (for example, Infura will throw `project ID request rate exceeded`).